# Hooks on terminal. Can I call a method before a command is run in the terminal?

Tags: c, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I am wanting to make a terminal app that stores information about files/directories. I want a way to keep the information if the file is moved or renamed.

What I thought I could do is have a function execute before any command is run. I found this:

http://www.twistedmatrix.com/users/glyph/preexec.bash.txt

But I was wondering if this would be a good way to go about it. Or should I do something else?

I would like to call that function from a C program whenever mv is entered I suppose.

Comment: Are you re-re-reimplementing the trashbin for the command line?

Comment: hmm no that was not what I was planning to make but thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is attach some sort of metadata to files, there's a much better supported way to do that -- [extended attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes).

Another solution might be to use the file's inode number as an index into a database you maintain yourself.

Comment: Yeah I have explored that. However, I want to have a central collection. For example, I might give a file the name "ruby". I then would like to see all the files that have the name "ruby" with them. So I was thinking I would have to store them in one file somewhere since I can't really search by extended attribute's and searching by inode number seems really slow.

Answer (score 0):

Can you alias the mv command?  in .profile or .bashrc

```
alias mv=/usr/bin/local/mymv
```

where mymv is a compiled executable that runs your C code function and calls /usr/bin/mv.

precmd and preeexec add some overhead to every bash script that gets run, even if the script never calls mv.  The downside to alias is that it requires new code in /usr/local and if scripts or users employ /usr/bin/mv instead of mv it will not do what you want.  Generally doing something like this often means there is a better way to handle the problem with some kind of service (daemon) or driver. Plus, what happens if your C code cannot correctly handle interesting input like

```
mv somefille /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run command each time after some command was executed in the terminal, just put the following in `~/.bashrc`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="your_command;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

If you want your command to be executed each time before mv is executing, put the following in `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias mv="your_script"
```

Make sure that your script will execute real `mv` if needed.

You can use [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) library to track filesystem changes. It's good solution, but once user remove file, it's already gone.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to make use of the [`DEBUG` `trap`](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#IDX86) in Bash.

From [`man bash`](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html):

> If  a sigspec is DEBUG, the command arg is executed before every
>                 simple command, for command, case command, select command, every
>                 arithmetic for command, and before the first command executes in
>                 a shell function

Answer (score 0):

I found this article when I was forced to work in tcsh and wanted to ensure a specific environemtn variable was present when the user ran a program from a certain folder (without setting that variable globally)

[tcsh](https://www.tcsh.org/) can do this.

tcsh has [special alias](http://www.kitebird.com/csh-tcsh-book/tcsh.html/Special_aliases.html), one of which is `precmd`
This can be used to run a script just before the shell prompt is printed.
e.g. I used `set precmd 'bash $HOME/.local/bin/on_cd.sh'`

This might be one of the very few useful features in `csh`.
It is a shame but I don't think the same or similar feature is in bash or other `sh` derivites (ash, dash etc). [Related answer.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145524/23754)